# multiple lines lookup in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet called SLA and another sheet as Worksheet

the SLA has a unique entry of Product IDs but the worksheet may have multiple entries of the same Product ID

for example:
SLA-

| Product ID | Target |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 30 |
| DEF2 | 30 |
| 567V | 30 |

Worksheet needs to update the `Target` column but only at the first entry of the Product ID-

| Product ID | Target |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1 | 30 |
| ABC1 |  |
| ABC1 |  |
| ABC1 |  |
| DEF2 | 30 |
| DEF2 |  |
| 567V | 30 |

I want to fill in the target column in the worksheet from SLA but just at the first row of each Product ID

how can I do this in google sheets using formula

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(countif(D2:Σ,Σ)=1,xlookup(Σ,A:A,B:B,),)))
```

- *adjust the formula as per your **tab names** and **ranges***

[image]

`logic`: ***first row of each Product ID** is figured by using `countif(D2:Σ,Σ)=1` & then using lookup to pull target value when condition is met*

Comment: This is super helpful, works like a charm! Thank you so much for such swift reply